# RStudio - Can't install package "xfun"

Tags: r

I installed the latest version of RStudio Desktop (x64) today. I have R version 4.0.2 (x64).
I want to create RMarkdown files from the File menu option in RStudio. I've only installed `rmarkkdown` and `tidyverse` in that order. The menu option tells me I need to update package `xfun` which I don't have.

Here's my console after attempting to install `xfun`:

```
> install.packages("xfun")

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
     binary source needs_compilation
xfun   0.16   0.17              TRUE

installing the source package ‘xfun’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/xfun_0.17.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 77239 bytes (75 KB)
downloaded 75 KB

* installing *source* package 'xfun' ...
** package 'xfun' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
d:/Cygwin64/bin/gcc  -I"D:/R_ProgrammingLanguage/R-4.0.2/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c base64.c -o base64.o
d:/Cygwin64/bin/gcc  -I"D:/R_ProgrammingLanguage/R-4.0.2/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c init.c -o init.o
d:/Cygwin64/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o xfun.dll tmp.def base64.o init.o -LD:/R_ProgrammingLanguage/R-4.0.2/bin/x64 -lR
installing to D:/R_ProgrammingLanguage/R-4.0.2/library/00LOCK-xfun/00new/xfun/libs/x64
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'xfun'
    finding HTML links ... done
    Rscript                                 html  
    Rscript_call                            html  
    attr                                    html  
    base64_encode                           html  
    base64_uri                              html  
    cache_rds                               html  
    download_file                           html  
    embed_file                              html  
    file_ext                                html  
    file_string                             html  
    gsub_file                               html  
    in_dir                                  html  
    install_dir                             html  
    install_github                          html  
    isFALSE                                 html  
    is_ascii                                html  
    native_encode                           html  
    normalize_path                          html  
    numbers_to_words                        html  
    optipng                                 html  
    os                                      html  
    parse_only                              html  
    pkg_attach                              html  
    prose_index                             html  
    protect_math                            html  
    raw_string                              html  
    read_utf8                               html  
    rename_seq                              html  
    rev_check                               html  
    rstudio_type                            html  
    same_path                               html  
    session_info                            html  
    split_lines                             html  
    split_source                            html  
    strict_list                             html  
    stringsAsStrings                        html  
    tojson                                  html  
    tree                                    html  
    try_silent                              html  
    upload_ftp                              html  
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
ERROR: loading failed
* removing 'D:/R_ProgrammingLanguage/R-4.0.2/library/xfun'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xfun’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQd7ojV\downloaded_packages’
```

This is the only edit in my `R-4.0.2/etc/x64/Makeconf` file:

```
BINPREF ?= d:/Cygwin64/bin/
```

I'm not sure what's going on. There's no helpful error message at the end.

Comment: Can you just install the binary version? `install.packages("xfun", type="binary")`

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! Do you happen to know why?